# How to install WebLogic server using Console mode in RHEL?

Tags: installation, weblogic, rhel, rhel6

In my REHL server I'm going to install **WebLogic** server, But while the installation it shows the following,

---

```
Launcher log file is /tmp/OraInstall2014-12-03_01-46-31AM/launcher2014-12-03_01-46-31AM.log.
```

Extracting files..............
Starting Oracle Universal Installer

Checking if CPU speed is above 300 MHz.   Actual 1997.386 MHz    Passed
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.  DISPLAY environment variable not set.    Failed <<<<
Checking swap space: must be greater than 512 MB.   Actual 4145148 MB    Passed
Checking if this platform requires a 64-bit JVM.   Actual 64    Passed (64-bit not required)
Checking temp space: must be greater than 300 MB.   Actual 953 MB    Passed

Some system prerequisite checks failed.
You must fulfill these requirements before continuing with the installation.

Continue? (yes [y] / no [n]) [n]

---

Then I tried install with **console** mode using the following command,

```
java -jar fmw_12.1.3.0.0_wls.jar -mode=console
```

But it says,

> Invalid argument(s): -mode=console

So can anyone help me to install the **WebLogic server** using **console mode**? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 6):

It would appear that the interactive console mode of installation has been taken out in this version (it was still there in 12.1.1).  The main documentation page [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/WLSIG/install_gui.htm#WLSIG125) now only mentions this example of running the installer which will attempts to start a graphical UI ...

```
/home/Oracle/jdk7_51/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java -jar fmw_12.1.3.0.0_wls.jar
```

However, [silent mode](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/OUIRF/silent.htm#OUIRF323) is still supported.  To install weblogic in the mode, you need to supply a response file containing the values for all the options you would previously have entered as you were going along.  Rather unhelpfully, the documentation suggests generating the initial version of this by running the graphical installer!

```
1. Run your product's graphical installer or deinstaller, 
   as described in your product installation guide.

2. For product installation, on the Installation Summary screen, 
   click Save Response File to save your installation parameters to a response file.
```

The only real questions it asks is for an Oracle Home directory and what type of installation you want to do (WebLogic Server, Coherence, Complete with Examples).  This is what I got for a WebLogic Server install in c:\oracle2 without a link to Oracle support for updates ...

```
[ENGINE]

#DO NOT CHANGE THIS.
Response File Version=1.0.0.0.0

[GENERIC]

#The oracle home location. This can be an existing Oracle Home or a new Oracle Home
ORACLE_HOME=c:\oracle2

#Set this variable value to the Installation Type selected. e.g. WebLogic Server, Coherence, Complete with Examples.
INSTALL_TYPE=WebLogic Server

#Provide the My Oracle Support Username. If you wish to ignore Oracle Configuration Manager configuration provide empty string for user name.
MYORACLESUPPORT_USERNAME=

#Provide the My Oracle Support Password
MYORACLESUPPORT_PASSWORD=<SECURE VALUE>

#Set this to true if you wish to decline the security updates. Setting this to true and providing empty string for My Oracle Support username will ignore the Oracle Configuration Manager configuration
DECLINE_SECURITY_UPDATES=true

#Set this to true if My Oracle Support Password is specified
SECURITY_UPDATES_VIA_MYORACLESUPPORT=false

#Provide the Proxy Host
PROXY_HOST=

#Provide the Proxy Port
PROXY_PORT=

#Provide the Proxy Username
PROXY_USER=

#Provide the Proxy Password
PROXY_PWD=<SECURE VALUE>

#Type String (URL format) Indicates the OCM Repeater URL which should be of the format [scheme[Http/Https]]://[repeater host]:[repeater port]
COLLECTOR_SUPPORTHUB_URL=
```

Comment: Still applicable with 12.2.1.2.0; must be installed using `-silent`. E.g.`java -jar fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls.jar -silent -responseFile /home/oracle/response/wls.rsp -invPtrLoc /home/oracle/inventory/oraInst.loc`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way to do this:

```
java -jar fmw_14.1.1.0.0_wls_lite_generic.jar -silent -responseFile /home/veloz/wblogic/responsefile.sh -invPtrLoc /home/veloz/oraInventory/oraInst.loc

and here is the responseFile:
[ENGINE]

#DO NOT CHANGE THIS.
Response File Version=1.0.0.0.0

[GENERIC]

#The oracle home location. This can be an existing Oracle Home or a new Oracle Home
#ORACLE_HOME=/scratch/Oracle/products/Oracle_Home
ORACLE_HOME=/home/veloz/OraHome_2

INVENTORY_LOCATION=/home/veloz/oraInventory

#Set this variable value to the Installation Type selected. e.g. WebLogic Server, Coherence, Complete with Examples.
#INSTALL_TYPE=WebLogic Server
INSTALL_TYPE=Complete with Examples

#Provide the My Oracle Support Username. If you wish to ignore Oracle Configuration Manager configuration provide empty string for user name.
MYORACLESUPPORT_USERNAME=

#Provide the My Oracle Support Password
MYORACLESUPPORT_PASSWORD=

#Set this to true if you wish to decline the security updates. Setting this to true and providing empty string for My Oracle Support username will ignore the Oracle Configuration Manager configuration
DECLINE_SECURITY_UPDATES=true

#Set this to true if My Oracle Support Password is specified
SECURITY_UPDATES_VIA_MYORACLESUPPORT=false

#Provide the Proxy Host
PROXY_HOST=localhost

#Provide the Proxy Port
PROXY_PORT=8081

#Provide the Proxy Username
PROXY_USER=

#Provide the Proxy Password
PROXY_PWD=

#Type String (URL format) Indicates the OCM Repeater URL which should be of the format [scheme[Http/Https]]://[repeater host]:[repeater port]
COLLECTOR_SUPPORTHUB_URL=
```

i take the information from:

1. https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/12.2.1.3/ouirf/using-oracle-universal-installer-silent-mode.html#GUID-C777FCC7-8A68-44B2-A9FD-9A69E75BC37C
2. [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53672_01/doc.111191/e53673/GUID-36A18CFA-55F1-4D19-B371-A6D15EBF2E24.htm#:~:text=Define%20the%20proxy%20host%20and%20the%20non-proxy%20hosts,-Dhttp.proxyHost%3Dwww-proxy.example.com%20-Dhttp.proxyPort%20-%20specifies%20the%20proxy%20host%20port](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53672_01/doc.111191/e53673/GUID-36A18CFA-55F1-4D19-B371-A6D15EBF2E24.htm#:%7E:text=Define%20the%20proxy%20host%20and%20the%20non-proxy%20hosts,-Dhttp.proxyHost%3Dwww-proxy.example.com%20-Dhttp.proxyPort%20-%20specifies%20the%20proxy%20host%20port).
3. https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/OUIRF/response_file.htm#OUIRF370